# Does StateHasChanged re-render all the component or only the differences?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am learning Blazor Component and I am wondering about StateHasChanged force the component to re-render all itself or only the differences. The intellisense report that

> Notifies the component that its state has changed. When applicable, this will cause the component to be re-rendered.

What it means with "this will cause the component to be re-rendered"?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0 -- After the component is initially rendered, the component regenerates its render tree in response to events. Blazor then compares the new render tree against the previous one and applies any modifications to the browser's Document Object Model (DOM).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

StateHasChanged will cause only the differences to be re-rendered.

To prove that, I've created the following Blazor component that has 2 buttons:

- first button generates a list of 10 000 `<li>` elements, numbered 0 .. 9999
- second button modifies the value of the first `<li>` and calls StateHasChanged()

Here is the complete code:

```cs
@page "/BigDataStateHasChanged"

<h3>BigDataStateHasChanged</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GenerateBigData">Generate big data</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeOneRow">Change 1 row</button>

@if(list != null)
{
    @foreach(var item in list)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
}

@code {
    List<int> list;
    const int cMaxNumbers = 10000;

    protected void GenerateBigData()
    {
        list = new List<int>(cMaxNumbers);
        for(int i = 0; i < cMaxNumbers; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
    }

    protected void ChangeOneRow()
    {
        list[0] = 123456;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

I then used the Chrome's development tools to monitor the websockets. On the Network tab, when clicking on the first button, I can see that 1.4 MB was transferred via the websockets to the client:

[image]

Then, after clicking the second button that only changes the first element, I can see that only 153 bytes have been transferred:

[image]

So, from this, the conclusion is that only the "diff" gets rendered.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: This is also because your component does not contain Razor Components and there's not dependencies or parameters between parent and child component.